# PHP Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2)

Tags: php

I have php file on web site ***c:\inetpub\www\domain.com\httpdocs\test.php***  with two lines below:

```
line 13    chdir('/app/files/'); 
line 14     include ('insert.php');
```

Willing to include the file at  ***c:\inetpub\www\domain.com\httpdocs\app\files\insert.php*** but having on log files as below:

*PHP Warning: chdir(): No such file or directory (errno 2) in C:\Inetpub\www\domain.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 13    php_error
PHP Warning: include(s_insert.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\www\domain.com\httpdocs\test.php on line 14*

I assume line 14 error due line 13 result. What missing in line 13 ? 
I set the open_basedir to none, should I leave as none ?

Comment: `chdir('/app/files/')` - that would change the working directory to `c:\app\files\` in your case.

Comment: There is a constant `__DIR__` which is the path to the current file. Just `include(__DIR__ . '/app/files/insert.php');`.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @VolkerK, the problem was solved with `chdir('/app/files/')`. That would change the working directory to `c:\app\files`.